# how can i perform double click using opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I want a code for double clicking with only these packages:

```
import cv2
import pyautogui
from HandTracker import HandDetector
import math
```

This is the code for handtracker:

```
import cv2
import mediapipe as mp
import time
import math
import numpy as np


class HandDetector():
    def __init__(self, imageMode=False, maxHands=2, modelComplexity=1 , detectionConfidence=0.5, trackingConfidence=0.5 ):

        self.imageMode = imageMode
        self.maxHands = maxHands
        self.modelComplexity = modelComplexity
        self.detectionConfidence = detectionConfidence
        self.trackingConfidence = trackingConfidence
        self.mpHands = mp.solutions.hands
        self.hands = self.mpHands.Hands(self.imageMode, self.maxHands, self.modelComplexity,  self.detectionConfidence, self.trackingConfidence)
        self.mpDraw = mp.solutions.drawing_utils
        self.tipIds = [4, 8, 12, 16, 20]


    def findHandLandmarks(self, cap):

        # X is the raw distance, Y is the value in cm.
        x = [300, 245, 200, 170, 145, 130, 112, 103, 93, 87, 80, 75, 70, 67, 62, 59, 57]
        y = [20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70, 75, 80, 85, 90, 95, 100]
        coff = np.polyfit(x, y, 2)

        isImageRead, image = cap.read()
        image = self.findHands(image)
        landmarksList, boundingbox = self.findPosition(image)

        try:
            _, x1, y1 = landmarksList[5]
            _, x2, y2 = landmarksList[17]

            distance = int(math.sqrt((y2 - y1)**2 + (x2 - x1)**2))
            A, B, C = coff
            distanceCM = A * distance**2 + B * distance + C

            if distanceCM < 40:
                text = 'Move your hand away'
                cv2.putText(image, text, (10, 70), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 2, (255, 0, 255), 3)
            if distanceCM > 90:
                text = 'Bring your hand closer'
                cv2.putText(image, text, (10, 70), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 2, (255, 0, 255), 3)
            if 90 >= distanceCM >= 40:
                text = f'{int(distanceCM)} cm'
                cv2.putText(image, text, (10, 70), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 3, (255, 0, 255), 3)

        except IndexError:
            pass

        return image

    def findHands(self, image, draw=True):

        imgRGB = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        self.results = self.hands.process(imgRGB)

        if self.results.multi_hand_landmarks:
            for handLandmarks in self.results.multi_hand_landmarks:
                if draw:
                  self.mpDraw.draw_landmarks(image, handLandmarks, self.mpHands.HAND_CONNECTIONS)

        return image


    def findPosition(self, image, handNo=0, draw=True):

        xList = []
        yList = []
        bbox = []
        self.landmarksList = []
        if self.results.multi_hand_landmarks:
            myHand = self.results.multi_hand_landmarks[handNo]
            for id, lm in enumerate(myHand.landmark):
                h, w, c = image.shape
                cx, cy = int(lm.x * w), int(lm.y * h)
                xList.append(cx)
                yList.append(cy)
                self.landmarksList.append([id, cx, cy])
                if draw:
                    cv2.circle(image, (cx, cy), 5, (255, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)

            xmin, xmax = min(xList), max(xList)
            ymin, ymax = min(yList), max(yList)
            bbox = xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax

            if draw:
                cv2.rectangle(image, (xmin - 20, ymin - 20), (xmax + 20, ymax + 20), (0, 255, 0), 2)

        return self.landmarksList, bbox


    def fingersMotion(self):

        # Fingers[] represents which fingers are up where 1 = up and 0 = down
        fingers = []

        # Thumb
        if self.landmarksList[self.tipIds[0]][1] > self.landmarksList[self.tipIds[0] - 1][1]:
            fingers.append(1)
        else:
            fingers.append(0)

        # Fingers
        for id in range(1, 5):
            if self.landmarksList[self.tipIds[id]][2] < self.landmarksList[self.tipIds[id] - 2][2]:
                fingers.append(1)
            else:
                fingers.append(0)

        return fingers


    def findDistance(self, p1, p2, image, draw=True, r=15, t=3):

        x1, y1 = self.landmarksList[p1][1:]
        x2, y2 = self.landmarksList[p2][1:]
        cx, cy = (x1 + x2) // 2, (y1 + y2) // 2

        if draw:
            cv2.line(image, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (255, 0, 255), t)
            cv2.circle(image, (x1, y1), r, (255, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)
            cv2.circle(image, (x2, y2), r, (255, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)
            cv2.circle(image, (cx, cy), r, (0, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)
        length = math.hypot(x2 - x1, y2 - y1)

        return length, image, [x1, y1, x2, y2, cx, cy]


def main():

    previousTime = 0
    currentTime = 0
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    detector = HandDetector()

    while True:
        image = detector.findHandLandmarks(cap)

        # Frame rate
        currentTime = time.time()
        framesPerSecond = 1 / (currentTime - previousTime)
        previousTime = currentTime
        cv2.putText(image, str(int(framesPerSecond)), (10, 70), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 3, (255, 0, 255), 3)

        # Display
        cv2.imshow("Image", image)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
            break


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Type error: `if name == "main": main()` should be  `if __name__ == "__main__":` main()

Comment: Please explain what you are going to do? What do you mean by "double click" in connection with hand tracking? What have you tried?